# define variables in the txt file using python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, parameter-passing, argparse, sys

i have one .txt file and i want to create python script with `sys.argv` or `argparse` or other package to define some variables in the txt file and i take some result.

i want to update the variables in the text file based on arguments passed to the python script

txt file maybe like this :

```
input number 1= %var1%
input number 2= %var2%
result = %vresult(var1-var2)%
```

must var1,var2 define by the user with some input in the python script and i take result(var1-var2 for ex)

i can to do this easy but i dont know how to connect arguments from the python script to txt.

how can i write a python script to update dynamic variables in the txt file ?

i dont want with replace i thing so arguments is the better.

Comment: Do you want to read the variables from the txt file with a python script? Or update the variables in the text file based on arguments passed to the python script? I'm trying to follow you but not quite getting it.

Comment: i want to update the variables in the text file based on arguments passed to the python script

Answer (score 1):

This is a different way using `regex` and a dictionary, and taking input using `sys.argv`:

```
import sys,re
v1 = sys.argv[1]
v2 = sys.argv[2]

with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    content = f.read()

repl = {'var1':v1, 'var2':v2}

repl_pattern = re.compile(r'(' + '|'.join(repl.keys()) + r')')
final_data = repl_pattern.sub(lambda x: repl[x.group()], content)

with open('file.txt','w') as new:
    new.write(final_data)
```

**results:**

The file.txt initially had the following content:

```
input number 1= var1
input number 2= var2
result = vresult(var1-var2)
```

and after running the above code (with: `sys.argv[1]=2` and `sys.argv[2]`=3) the file changed to:

```
input number 1= 3
input number 2= 2
result = vresult(3-2)
```

If you want `result = 1` instead of `result = vresult(3-2)` then add this code:

```
result = str(int(v1)-int(v2))
key3 = 'vresult('+v1+'-'+v2+')'
final_data = final_data.replace(key3,result)
```

just before the `with open('file.txt','w') as new:` ....

Comment: i follow your code but show me 'IndexError: list index out of range' in the line 2,v1 = sys.argv[1] and i change to v1 = sys.argv[1]=2 again show me that error,why ?i am user python 2.7

Comment: @ChrisPapas  you don't have to/shouldn't give values to `sys.argv` internally, if you name the script e.g. test.py, try run it like: `python test.py 3 2` and make sure that you change the filename from file.txt to whatever file-name you are using. I also use python 2.7 and I had no problem ...

Comment: from cmd line yes,but the progress i want and must to run in the script not cmd line.

Comment: @ChrisPapas  You said in your post that you wanted to use `sys.argv`, which means taking the inputs from cmd. Now if you want to insert them in the script manually you can use `raw_input` instead to give values to `v1/v2` -  there are many ways to give these variables a value, which to use depends on what you want to do. Anyway this is not a complete script, just demonstrates the idea to modify variables in a .txt from a .py script. Modify it so it fits your needs ...

Comment: yes my bad my mistake for sys.argv sorry for that,now i follow your details to change  `sys ` to  `raw_input `.

Answer (score 0):

There's almost certainly a better way to do this but it sounded like an interesting problem so I decided to give it a try. I defined a text file with variable names listed as such:

**newfile.txt:**

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 3
```

By reading one line at a type and conforming to the "var = value" input format, you can parse the text file for the correct variable then re-write the file with the new value.

```
import fnmatch


var2change = "z = 17"
identifier = var2change.split('=')[0] # Get variable name

# Read file
file = open('newfile.txt', 'r')
fileLines = file.read()
fileLines = fileLines.splitlines()

for lineNum,var in enumerate(fileLines):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(str(var),''.join([identifier,'*'])): break # Found variable to change

file.close()

file = open("newfile.txt", "w")
for ln, data in enumerate(fileLines):
    if ln == lineNum:
        lineToWrite = ''.join([var2change, '\n'])
    else:
        lineToWrite = ''.join([data, '\n'])

    file.write(lineToWrite)

file.close()
```

This will re-write the file to read:

**newfile.txt:**

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 17
```

Answer (score 0):

parameter.txt file contains:

```
variable1=10
variable2=20
```

Below is the python code:

```
variable1=0
variable2=0
with open('parameters.txt') as f:
    para_list = [i.strip() for i in f.readlines()]
    for para in para_list:
        exec(para)
    print('sum = {}'.format(variable1+variable2))
```

Below is the result:

sum = 30